# Django form_valid is not working

Tags: python, django

I am new to django . Can anyone help me with this code. I am trying to calculate duration between 2 DateField then save.

```
class EmployeeCreate(CreateView):
    model = Employee
    form_class = EmployeeCreateForm
    success_url = "/employee-list/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object.total_leave = (self.object.to_date - self.object.from_date).days +1
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: I cant calculate and save total_leave. Its not saving anything

Comment: Now getting error  Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'total_leave'

Answer (score 6):

There are couple of issues

1. You should use `form.instance` instead of `self.object`
2. Call super method

So update your code as:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.total_leave = (self.instance.to_date - self.instance.from_date).days +1
    form.instance.save()
    return super(EmployeeCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Refer docs [Form handling with class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)

Comment: Getting error:  Exception Value: 'EmployeeCreate' object has no attribute 'instance'

Comment: def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.total_leave = (form.instance.to_date -       form.instance.from_date).days +1
        form.instance.save()
        return super(LeaveCreate, self).form_valid(form)

Comment: Another silly question how do i check if there any value in Field leave_balance , I want to calculate the leave_balance from another relational table First time  there is   leave_type    =  models.ForeignKey(Leavetype)    First time i want like Leavetype.leave_duration - total_leave

Comment: Is the actual answer wrong?  We should edit this to be correct.  I was confused when I first got here.

Comment: @trpt4him, answer is correct, OP got error due to typo.

Answer (score 3):

Because of `CreateView` first of all you have to save form to get an object.

Do not persisting object to database for futher customization(`commit=False`).

Then change object to fit your requirements. Finally persist object in database and return redirect response.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.total_leave = (self.object.to_date - self.object.from_date).days + 1
    self.object.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Also look at basic `form_valid` implementation in `ModelFormMixin`:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save()
    return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

Then `super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)` chained to `FormMixin`:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

So we combined both steps in one method.